# Is there a way to save and restore the call stack in C

Tags: c, stack, callstack

I'd like to create two threads of execution, execute two different functions and then use the same call stack to return. The execution does not need to be in parallel, the threads of execution can be executed one after another.

I've tried to solve the problem with setcontext/getcontext, but they do not copy the complete call stack and the second thread cannot use the call stack of the first thread:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ucontext.h>

ucontext_t fork_context, fork_context2;
char stack[SIGSTKSZ];
int end = 0;

void func2_1() {
  printf("func2_1\n");
}


void func2_2() {
  printf("func2_2\n");
  end = 1;
}

void func2() {
  printf("func2\n");
  func2_1();

  getcontext(&fork_context);
  fork_context.uc_link          = &fork_context2;
  fork_context.uc_stack.ss_sp   = stack;
  fork_context.uc_stack.ss_size = sizeof(stack);
  makecontext(&fork_context, (void (*)(void)) func2_2, 0);
}

void func1() {
  printf("enter func1\n");
  func2();
  getcontext(&fork_context2);
  printf("return func1\n");
}


int main(void) {
  func1();
  printf("back in main\n\n");

  if (end != 1) {
    setcontext(&fork_context);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

In `func2()` I'd like to execute `func2_1()` and then return according to the call stack. Before returning from `main()` I'd like to execute `func2_2()` and return to the same functions as when I returned from `func2_1()`. The code above produces the following output:

```
func2_1
return func1
back in main

func2_2
return func1
```

`func2_2()` is called correctly and then execution is continued in `func1()`, but `func1()` does not return back to `main()`, because the stack frame of the `func1()` call was already removed. I'd like a program that produces the following output:

```
func2_1
return func1
back in main

func2_2
return func1
back in main
```

One possibility would be to use POSIX `fork()` as it copies the whole process (including the call stack), but I'd rather not use `fork()` if possible.

Comment: C doesn't really support accessing the stack directly, it manages it for you.  I don't really understand what you mean by having 2 functions return to the same place on the stack.  Do you want two threads seeing the same stack but potentially doing different things with it?  Another question about getting to the stack is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847053/how-to-get-address-of-base-stack-pointer

Comment: There is not a way to do this 'in c' because the stack is an implementation detail.  There might be a platform-specific way to do what you want, but this sounds like the kind of thing that's unlikely to work reliably, if at all.  I think you need to back up and think about the semantics of what you're trying to accomplish before you start thinking about the solution.

Comment: There's no (POSIX-defined) way to copy a call-stack in a single process like you seem to be suggesting. You'll need to represent state explicitly in your own data structures.

Answer (score 3):

I can't help thinking that `fork()` is the simplest solution to this problem, although you might need some shared memory in order to allow the results of the two invocations to be merged. It's not quite true that `fork()` copies the entire process structure; it is usually implemented with copy-on-write for individual virtual memory pages, so it only ends up copying that part of the state which is modified; that doesn't include the process's code, for example.

If you want to do it yourself, you can use the posix thread library's `pthread_attr_setstack` to create a thread with a specific stack, which you need to allocate yourself. Since you're in control of the stack memory, you're free to `memcpy` it in order to preserve it. In theory, at least, you could then create another thread with the copied stack and use the now-deprecated `getcontext` and friends to save and restore the part of the call state which is not in the stack. To copy the stack efficiently, you'll need to know its limit; there are various ways to do this, but none of them are platform independent.

If what you're after is to provide a C implementation of `call/cc`, you might want to take a look at the classic implementation in Chicken Scheme (http://www.call-cc.org), which takes a lot of interesting liberties with the C stack, apparently successfully.

Comment: rici, could you please explain, what kind of problems could be solved using this trick?

Comment: @alexander: You should probably ask the questioner why s/he wants it :) Here's a wikipedia article which is relevant, although all the examples are in scheme: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimited_continuation. "This trick" would let you write similar code in C (although you'd probably need some preprocessing tricks to make it readable). You can think of a "delimited continuation" as essentially a (segment of) the call stack, although that's imprecise and implementation-specific.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to save and restore the call stack in C

No. How exactly the stack behaves (whether and which function parameters are passed in registers or on the stack, what registers must be saved/restored, etc.) is a function of the active ABI and CPU (e.g. the Linux ELF ABI is a bit different on amd64 than on x86, and any OS may simultaneously support more than one ABI) and *C* knows nothing about it. It might be possible to do through some platform-specific API, but that's not really a *C* issue.

> I'd like to create two threads of execution, execute two different functions

Do you want to create two new threads or create one additional thread in addition to the main thread? If you create a new thread in the main thread, there are now two threads of execution, but you have only created one (additional) thread.

Any functions called by the “start routine” of the new thread (or called by those functions, etc.) will execute in the new thread. All functions called by `main()`, or called by functions called by `main()` (and so on) will execute in the main thread.

> and then use the same call stack to return.

Huh? Use the same *as what* stack to return *what* from *where*? On it's own that clause is just confusing!

> The execution does not need to be in parallel, the threads of execution can be executed one after another.

Then why create a second thread at all and not just call the functions in sequence?

> I've tried to solve the problem with setcontext/getcontext

Don't do that. Those functions were formally deprecated in 2001 and no longer appear in POSIX/SUS. New applications (or those written in the last decade) should be using POSIX threads instead.

Here is a POSIX threads program that crudely mirrors what you seemed to be trying to do in your code extract, but honestly, I'm not sure how close I got because it really isn't clear to me what you're trying to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define bail(err, msg) { \
    errno = err;         \
    perror(msg);         \
    exit(1);             \
}


pthread_t tid;

// Executes in the main thread
void func2_1() {
    printf("func2_1\n");
}

// Conforms to prototype expected by pthread_create(); executes in new
// thread.
void *func2_2(void *arg) {
    (void)arg;
    printf("func2_2\n");

    // I suppose we just exit here, since there's nothing else for
    // this thread to do:
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

// Executes in main thread
void func2() {
    int rc; // Return code

    printf("enter func2\n");

    func2_1(); // Executes in main thread

    rc = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, func2_2, NULL);
    if(rc) {
        bail(rc, "pthread_create() failed")
    }

    printf("return func2\n");
}

// Executes in main thread
void func1() {
    printf("enter func1\n");
    func2();
    printf("return func1\n");
}


int main(void) {
    int rc; // Return code

    func1();
    printf("back in main\n\n");

    rc = pthread_join( tid, NULL );
    if(rc) {
        bail(rc, "pthread_join() failed");
    }

    printf("returning from main()\n");
    return 0;
}
```